# enhancing mysql large table update

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update

I have the following two mysql (X and mode) tables with the following structure

```
 table X
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `op_mode` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` double NOT NULL,
  `processed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `processed` (`processed`)
```

---

```
table mode 
`time_from` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `time_to` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `op_mode` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL
```

table `X` contains around ~ 1M rows. 
    I have created a C# desktop app to update `op_mode` column of `X` table using the following query:

```
UPDATE X, mode
SET X.op_mode = mode.op_mode,
    processed = 1
WHERE (X.TIME BETWEEN mode.time_from
                  AND mode.time_to
) AND processed = 0
```

But the update process takes very long time.

Is there any suggestion to enhance the update process?

`processed` column in `X` table used as a flag (initially set to `0`, and set to `1` when row is updated)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many rows 'mode' has. If it is relatively few (less than 100), you're probably better off iterating over each row in your code and just doing a straight update to X

```
UPDATE X
SET X.op_mode = ?
    processed = 1
WHERE (X.TIME BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
AND processed = 0
```

This query will use the index on time and be much faster.

For new data, it will probably be best to set the op_mode via an insert trigger on X.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that table `mode` is relatively big, and that `time_from`-`time_to` ranges in that table never overlap (otherwise your schema would not make much sense).

In that case, you should add indexes in `mode` table on these fields either using non-standard `KEY`, or using

```
CREATE INDEX mode_time_from ON mode (time_from);
CREATE INDEX mode_time_to   ON mode (time_to);
```

In addition to that, having following compound index should improve speed even more:

```
CREATE INDEX x_processed_time ON X (processed, time);
```

Comment: thanks mvp for your reply, I have changed my db schema. unfortunately it took longer time to update than before